# How to update pointers when pushed on to std::stack using iteration?

Tags: c++, stack, iteration, binary-tree, pass-by-reference

Here is the situation:

> Given a pointer to the root of a binary search tree(of integers) `root` and an
>   integer `data`, perform the `rotate` function (predefined) on all the
>   ancestral nodes of the node containing `data` using iterative method. For simplicity, assume
>   `data` exists and always occurs on the leaf nodes.

The `rotate` function passes the pointer by reference as follows:

```
struct Node
{
    Node *left;
    int data;
    Node *right;
};

void rotate(Node* &root); // performs some rotation on the root and reflects the change.

void search(Node* &root, int data)
{
    stack<Node*> s;
    while(root->data!=data)
    {
        s.push(root);
        if(data<root->data)
            root=root->left;
        else
            root=root->right;
    }

    while(!s.empty())
    {
        rotate(s.top()); // does not reflect changes to root
        s.pop();
    }
}
```

The iterative version requires the use of a stack. `std::stack::push()` function pushes the pointer by value. As a result, while popping the ancestral pointers, I would be reflecting changes in the stack instead.

**What is the best work around for this situation?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This solves my problem.

```
void search(Node* &root, int data)
{   
    if(root->data==data)
        return;

    stack<Node**> s;
    while(root->data!=data)
    {
        if(data<root->data)
        {
            s.push(&root->left);
            root=root->left;
        }
        else
        {
            s.push(&root->right);
            root=root->right;
        }
    }
    s.pop(); // to avoid leaf
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        rotate(*s.top())
        s.pop();
    }
    rotate(root);
}
```

Comment: Please do not rollback changes of this nature when performed by a ♦ moderator.